# How can I delay variable interpolation in a regex to the point of use?

Tags: regex, perl

For example, let's imagine that I have a set of variables and an array of regexes that interpolate those variables:

```
my ($var1, $var2, $var3);
my @search_regexes=(
  qr/foo $var1/,
  qr/foo bar $var2/,
  qr/foo bar baz $var3/,
);
```

The above code will give us warnings telling us that `$var1`, `$var2` and `$var3` are not defined at the point of regex compilation for the regexes in `$search_regexes`. However, I want to delay variable interpolation in those regexes until the point they are actually used (or later (re)compiled once the variables have values):

```
# Later on we assign a value to $var1 and search for the first regex in $_ ...
$var1='Hello';
if (/$search_regexes[0]/)
{
  # Do something ...
}
```

How would I go about restructuring the construct in the initial code sample to allow for this?

As a bonus, I would like to compile each regex after a value is assigned to the respective variable(s) appearing in that regex in the same way that the `qr//` operator is doing now (but too early). If you can show how to further extend the solution to allow for this, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Update:**

I have settled on a variant of Hunter's approach, because using it I don't take a performance hit and there are minimal changes to my existing code. Other answers also taught me quite a bit about alternative solutions to this problem and their performance implications when very many lines need to be matched. My code now resembles the following:

```
my ($var1, $var2, $var3);
my @search_regexes=(
  sub {qr/foo $var1/},
  sub {qr/foo bar $var2/},
  sub {qr/foo bar baz $var3/},
);

...
($var1,$var2,$var3)=qw(Hello there Mr);

my $search_regex=$search_regexes[$based_on_something]->();

while (<>)
{
  if (/$search_regex/)
  {
    # Do something ...
    # and sometimes change $search_regex to be another from the array
  }

}
```

This gets me what I was looking for with minimal changes to my code (i.e., just the addition of subs to the array up top) and no performance hit per regex usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think if you wrap each regular expression in anonymous sub, you can do this sort of deferral:

```
my ($var1, $var2, $var3);
my @search_regexes=(
  sub { return qr/foo $var1/         },
  sub { return qr/foo bar $var2/     },
  sub { return qr/foo bar baz $var3/ },
);
```

Then when you are going to evaluate them you just 'call' the anonymous sub:

```
($var1, $var2, $var3) = qw(thunk this code);
if( $_ =~ $search_regexes[0]->() ) {
   # Do something
}
```

I know in Scheme this is called [thunking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_%28functional_programming%29) I am not sure if it has a name in Perl. You can do something similar in Ruby with [Proc objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html)

Comment: Very interesting! How can I add regex compilation to this construct, or do I even need to?

Comment: I don't think you need to, when you call the anonymous sub it should perform the interpolation and return the qr// compiled pattern. (I don't think that qr// is guaranteed to always compile the regex)

Comment: Perl won't execute subs in strings or regexes – that would have to be `$_ =~ $search_regexes[0]()` or `/@{[$search_regexes[0]()]}/`.

Comment: Would using a sub in this way reduce efficiency? I am comparing with millions of lines of text and am wondering if having a sub-call at every match would be a performance hit.

Comment: @amon Interesting, do you happen to know why? Seems like it would be similar to other dereferences that can occur inside `//`. Also wouldn't I need `->()`?

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Yes, involving a subroutine will reduce efficiency.   Using object orientation (as in my answer) even more. The only way around that is to somehow compile the regexes before you are going to match them. This could be limited by invoking all subs before any one is going to match, e.g. `$_ = $_->() for @search_regexes`, which only pays the performance price once, not over and over again. Even faster: don't specify the regexes before all involved variables are assigned.

Comment: @amon do you know how well Memoize performs?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen (1) Larry seems to have found that to error-prone, and now it can't be changed because of back-compat. (2) The `->()` can always be used, Except for normal subs, and it's optional when following another subscript (the normal rule applies here that `lr->LR` == `lrlr` where `lr` and `LR` are any of `[]`,`{}`,`()`). That rule doesn't hold after a normal sub invocation, e.g. in `foo()->[0]` the arrow *is* required.

Comment: @mpapec Not *that* well. MJD talks about memoization in his *Higher Order Perl* book, and shows examples where it can make sense (e.g. recursively calculating the factorial), and where it doesn't (e.g. the builtin `sqrt`). Memoization can make a program faster by reducing the algorithmic complexity (see also dynamic programming), but in the worst case (which is possibly the case here), the overhead weighs more than the actual computation itself.

Comment: Hi Hunter, your approach worked out the best in my code and so I have given you the checkmark.

Comment: Making $var1 (etc) a parameter would save you from making it a global var.

Answer (score 11):

The best solution would be to defer the compilation of the regex until those variables are defined. But first a questionable solution: Regexes can include code: `qr/foo (??{ $var1 })/`. The block is executed during the match, and the result of the block is then used as a pattern.

How can we defer the compilation?

1. By simply specifying them when the variables have been assigned. This is less of a problem as you might think, as any program can be expressed without (re-)assigning variables. Stick to the rule that any declaration must also be an assignment (and vice versa), and this should work. This:

   ```
   my $var1;
   my $re = qr/$var1/;
   $var1 = ...;
   $bar =~ $re;
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   my $var1 = ...;
   $re = qr/$var1/;
   $bar =~ $re;
   ```
2. If this isn't possible, we might want to use a closure that we evaluate before matching:

   ```
   my $var1;
   my $deferred_re = sub { qr/$var1/ };
   $var1 = ...;
   $bar =~ $deferred_re->();
   ```

   Of course this would recompile the regex at each invocation.
3. We can extend the previous idea by caching the regex:

   ```
   package DeferredRegexp;
   use overload 'qr' => sub {
     my ($self) = @_;
     return $self->[0] //= $self->[1]->();
   };

   sub new {
      my ($class, $callback) = @_;
      return bless [undef, $callback] => $class;
   }
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   my $var1;
   my $deferred_re = DeferredRegexp->new(sub{ qr/$var1/ });
   $var1 = ...;
   $bar =~ $deferred_re;
   ```

Comment: In #2, making $var1 a parameter would save you from making it a global var.

Answer (score 3):

`(??{ })` does exactly what you ask for.

```
our $var1;
my $re = qr/foo (??{ $var1 )/;
...
local $var1 = ...;
/$re/
```

But that's very awkward. The original string is what is called a template. There are numerous templating systems available that would make this cleaner.

```
my $pat_template = 'foo [% var1 %]';
...
Template->new->process($pat_template, { var1 => ... }, \my $pat);
/$pat/
```

If the template doesn't need to be stored in a file, you could use a builder sub.

```
my $re_gen = sub { my ($var1) = @_; qr/foo $var1/ };
...
my $re = $re_gen->(...);
/$re/
```

---

Note: Inside of `(??{ })`, you can run into problem using of lexical variables declared on the outside. That's why I used a package variable in the first snippet.

Answer (score 2):

[Amon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21760406/3686300) is the most complete. However, the question is why would you want to pre-compile your regular expressions if you're not 100% sure what they should be?

Like any compilation, everything has to be resolved at the time of compile. You can, as amon showed you, state your regular expression with variables, but that will recompile your regular expression when you call them again.

I suspect that you're not worried about compile time as simple reuse. If you use these regular expressions over and over again, isn't it better to have only a single place where they're maintained?

Well, that sounds like what a subroutine is for:

```
sub test_regex {
    my $test_val  = shift;
    my $regex_val = shift;
    my $regex_num = shift;

    if ( not defined $regex_num     # Need both parameters
       die qq(Invalid call to subroutine test_regex);
    }

    if    ( $regex_num == 0 ) {
       return $test_val =~ /foo $regex_val/;
    }
    elsif ( $regex_num == 1 ) {
       return $test_val =~ /foo bar $regex_val/;
    }
    elsif ( $regex_num == 2 ) {
       return $test_val =~ /foo bar bas $regex_val/;
    }
    else {
       die qq(Invalid value for regular expression value);
    }
}
```

Now, you can call `test_regex` like this:

```
if ( test_regex ( $_, $var1, 1 ) ) {
    say "This is a regular expression match!";
}
else {
    say "No it didn't match";
}
```

You have a single point where you have to maintain your regular expressions (in your subroutine), but you still have the flexibility to call them over and over again. Note that I have to pass three parameters: What I am testing (it could be `$_`, but maybe not), the value of `$var1`, and the subroutine number.

I *could* have used global values in my subroutine, but that's usually a bad idea:

```
sub test_regex {
   my regex_num = shift;   # Only thing I need. I'm assuming `$_` and `$var1` are global

    if ( not defined $regex_num     # Need both parameters
       die qq(Invalid call to subroutine test_regex);
    }

    if    ( $regex_num == 0 ) {
       return /foo $val1/;
    }
    elsif ( $regex_num == 1 ) {
       return /foo bar $val1/;
    }
    elsif ( $regex_num == 2 ) {
       return $test_val =~ /foo bar bas $val1/;
    }
    else {
       die qq(Invalid value for regular expression value);
    }
}
```

Then the call would be:

```
$val1 = 'fubar'
if ( test_regex( 1 ) ) {
    ....
}
```

It's more in line what you had, but it's not a good idea.

Answer (score -3):

If these are just character strings, try wrapping them in single quotes:

```
my ($var1, $var2, $var3);
my @search_regexes=(
  'foo $var1',
  'foo bar $var2',
  'foo bar baz $var3',
);
```

That should certainly keep the variables from being interpolated when the array is defined, but I can't promise that they'll interpolate when you actually use them. Give it a try, anyway.

Comment: So far, this seems to be half of the answer. How do I then use them as compiled regexes with variable interpolation?

Comment: Does it fail to interpolate them when used?

Comment: You said you "can't promise" - I can promise that they *won't* be interpolated.